# Failed to generate dynamic key in object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have initialized an empty object in which I am dynamically creating a key and inserting values into it inside for loop. But the issue is it's only taking the last value.

Why is this happening? What correction do I need here?

```js
const obj = {};
const filteredArr = {
  'Asia': ['India', 'China', 'Pakistan'],
  'Europe': ['Germany']
}

const uniqCountry = ['Italy', 'Japan', 'Russia', 'Poland'];

for (const key in filteredArr) {
  const values = filteredArr[key];
  for (const value of values) {
    if (uniqCountry.includes(value)) {
      if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        obj[key].push(value);
      } else {
        obj['Rest'] = [];
        obj['Rest'].push(value);
        console.log('rest', obj['Rest']);
      }
    }
  }
}
console.log('Object', obj);
```

Output:

```
{}
```

Expected Output:

```
{
  'Rest': ['Italy', 'Japan', 'Russia', 'Poland']
}
```

Comment: Completely unclear what kind of logic you're aiming for here. None of the values in your `filteredArray` are in `uniqCountry` so you're getting an empty result.

Comment: The expected output seems to make little sense given the input. Please add more detail to the question, describing the logic which needs to be executed.

Comment: You have `obj['Rest'] = [];` as the first line of the `else`, it means that it erases all values precedently stored in `obj['Rest']` by replacing to a new empty array. You should try with `if(!obj['Rest']}{ obj['Rest'] = []; }`. For the rest I agree, what you want to achieve is not very clear

Comment: SO here I have predefined object of regions having country array corresponding to it `filteredArr` and I have array of countries coming from db which is `uniqCountry`.Now I am checking if any of the country from `uniqCountry` array is available in `filteredArr` object if it then I am adding it into `obj` if that key is already exists if not then I am creating new key named `Rest` and adding those countries into it.

Comment: @Digvijay `None of the values in your filteredArray are in uniqCountry so you're getting an empty result` as Robby Cornelissen said.

Comment: So, as a result, you want an object with continent keys (Asia, Europe), and for every continent you want an array of the countries of that continent that also appear in `uniqCountry`? And for all the countries in `uniqCountry` that are not found in any continent, you want to add them to a `Rest` key? Please clarify your question itself and provide some more representative sample data.

Comment: `obj.hasOwnProperty(key)` will never be true (since `obj` is initialized as `{}`), so `obj[key].push(value);` will never be executed and the `Rest` key will be (re)added on every iteration.

Answer (score 1):

The question is not so clear but this shows something like you asked for. I did added 'Italy' to the filteredArr and 'India' to the uniqCountry to show those examples as well.

```js
const obj = {};
const filteredArr = {
  'Asia': ['India', 'China', 'Pakistan'],
  'Europe': ['Germany', 'Italy']
}

let uniqCountry = ['Italy', 'Japan', 'Russia', 'Poland', 'India'];

for (const key in filteredArr) {
  const values = filteredArr[key];
  for (const value of values) {
    if (uniqCountry.includes(value)) {
      if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        obj[key] = [...(obj[key] ?? []), value];
        uniqCountry = uniqCountry.filter(u => u !== value);
      }
    }
  }
}
obj['Rest'] = uniqCountry;
console.log('Object', obj);
```